# Keyword error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

[image]

```
public string ss = "Data Source=D\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=gym;Integrated Security=True";

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string q2 = "insert into database.gym (name,weight,height,add_class,gender,fees) values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.Text + "','" + this.comboBox2.Text + "','" + this.comboBox3.Text + " ') ;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ss);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q2, con);
        SqlDataReader read;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to our gym");
            while (read.Read()) { };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: what is database in those query?

Comment: `Database` is a *reserved* keyword in `Sql Server`. Do you really have schema named `Database` ?

Comment: From connection string, the database name is gym. The correct syntax would be **databasename.schema.tablename** for insert queries. Your command needs to be `INSERT INTO gym.schema.table`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: i did what you said but there is still an error ("incorrect syntax near keyword schema")

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into database.gym
```

Instead of this use a valid table name

```
insert into Table
```

The Correct Syntax is `[Database].[Schema].[TableName]`

Comment: an error appear("invalid object name gym.schema.customer").. what should i do?? @saurabh

Comment: You are not supposed to use word schema , Try gym.dbo.customer . Replace schema with dbo

Comment: i tried gym.dbo.customer also but another error appear "invalid object name gym.dbo.customer"

Comment: Please check again , gym should be your database name and customer should be your table name . If nothing works for you than go to view menu -> Server explore and connect to your database server . You will get your correct and working connection string there